# How do I solve this, first I have to factor $ 2x\over x-1$ + $ 3x +1\over x-1$ - $ 1 + 9x + 2x^2\over x^2-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, fractions

I am doing calculus exercises but I'm in trouble with this

$$\frac{ 2x}{x-1} +  \frac{3x +1}{ x-1} -   \frac{1 + 9x + 2x^2}{x^2-1}$$

the solution is

> $$ 3x\over x+1$$

The only advance that I have done is factor $ x^2-1$ = $( x-1)$ $ (x+1)$.

I do not know how can I factor  $1 + 9x + 2x^2$, can someone please guide me in how to solve this exercise.

Comment: what are you trying to solve?

Comment: simplify the algebraic expression in the question

Comment: make all denominators the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that  $$\frac{A}{B} + \frac{A'}{BC} = \frac{C}{C}\frac{A}{B} + \frac{A'}{BC} = \frac{AC + A'}{BC}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}\frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)}\frac{2x}{(x-1)}+&\frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)}\frac{3x+1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1 + 9x + 2x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}\\&=\frac{2x(x+1) + (3x+1)(x+1) - (1+9x + 2x^2)}{(x-1)(x+1)} \\&= \frac{2x^2 + 2x + 3x^2+3x + x + 1 - 1-9x - 2x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}\\&=\frac{3x^2 - 3x}{(x-1)(x+1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: at the end I have (3x^2 - 3x)/(x+1)(x-1) just with common factor 3x(x -1) /(x+1)(x-1) and then I get 3x/x+1 thanks for answering

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The first two terms are already over a common denominator.

First simplify $$\frac {2x}{x-1}+\frac {3x+1}{x-1}-\frac {1+9x+2x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac {5x+1}{x-1}-\frac {1+9x+2x^2}{x^2-1}$$

Then put the first fraction over the same denominator as the second $$\frac {(5x+1)(x+1)}{x^2-1}-\frac {1+9x+2x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac {(5x+1)(x+1)-(1+9x+2x^2)}{x^2-1}$$

Now simplify the numerator

Comment: thanks for answering I understand everything

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first two terms by $x+1$ in nominator and denominator. Then add all three terms and you obtain an expression 
$$\frac{f(x)}{(x-1)(x+1)}. $$
Now see how to factor $f(x)=3x^2-3x$.

Comment: you must compute $\frac{2x}{x-1}=\frac{2x(x+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$ etc

Comment: thanks for answering I understand the complete process